# 2013: load custom "clienttemplates.js" file

Tags: 2013, javascript, master-page, custom, file

Requirement:
I want to replace the file `clienttemplates.js` found in `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS`
with a custom version.
I couldn't find the place where this file is loaded so that I could load my version there.
Ideally I could modify the masterpage for it; I don't want to go the path of trying to hook into SP's JavaScript execution stack, I simply want to replace that file for certain sites.

NOTE: I have Minimal Download Strategy activated.

Comment: Why would you ever want to replace an OOTB file? Add your own besides the normal one and overwrite what you have to instead

Comment: I'd do this if I'd know where to inject my file to firstly not be loaded before `clienttemplates.js` and not secondly not too late so that SP's rendering mechanism doesn't pick up the original version before mine is loaded.

Comment: What are you really trying to do? :)

Comment: I have custom JavaScript code which I want to have certain webparts be rendered with. I have multiple webparts on one page. I leverage the templating system (Header,Body,OnPostRender, etc.) for this and hook custom code according to the calling webpart. I want to MDS so the "normal" template overriding doesn't do the trick... I have it already working but I don't want to touch the OOTB file as you also said; that's why I want to replace it (or the function `RenderListView`).

Comment: Getting JSLink to work with MDS is not really brain surgery

Comment: Here is all code I ever had to use for making it MDS proof 
 `RegisterModuleInit("PATHTOJS/publicDocumentTemplates.js", Fishbone.JSLinkTemplates.Render); 
Fishbone.JSLinkTemplates.Render();`